# how solve the sequence in assembly language

Tags: assembly

how i solve the following sequence in Assembly language:

R1=-2+4-6+8-10.....+-N

note : N value as input

Comment: sorry i change the question

Comment: That sequence has an explicit solution (i.e. one that doesn't need summing all the terms). Are you looking for one that just gives the correct value, or one that actually evaluates the sum as you write it in the question?

Comment: i wont the assembly language in correct value

Comment: i.e R2=1+2+3+4+...+6 
 we solved as (R*(R+1))/2 That mains (6*7)/2=21
 then in assembly language like that 

Mov R,6
ADD R,1
MUL R
DIV R,2
HLT

Comment: Which assembly language (16-bit x86, 64-bit x86, MIPS, ARM, Sparc, ...)?

Answer (score 1):

Look at a few values of this to find the pattern:

```
N     R1
2     -2
4     +2
6     -4
8     +4
10    -6
12    +6
```

So, when `N%4 == 0`, then `R1 = N/2`, and when `N%4 == 2`, then `R1 = -(N/2 + 1)`.

So in order to calculate this, you'd do the following (pseudocode, but will translate to assembly easily)

```
     if N%2 is not 0 then error: invalid input
     R1 = N/2
     if N%4 == 0 then jump to done
     R1 = R1 + 1
     R1 = -R1
   done:
```

Answer (score -1):

```
It is an arithmetico geometric progression with a = -2, d = -2 , r = -1
an = (a + (n-1)*d)*(r^(n-1))
N = an = 2*n*((-1)^n)
n = absolute(N) / 2                                                     -1
R1 = Sn
on solving you will get
R1 = ((-1)^n)*n - ( 1 + (-1)^(n-1) )/2                                  -2
```

You can use eqn 1 and 2 to get R1. Here is sample in C

```
#include<math.h>

int main() { 
float nlast,n,r1;
nlast = 12;
n = abs(nlast) / 2;
r1 = pow(-1,n)*n - ( 1 + pow(-1,n-1) )/2;
return(r1);
}
```

You can use this [site](http://assembly.ynh.io/) to get the assembly code.

Comment: It's not a geometric progression.

Comment: @us2012 I know that, it is sum of geometric progression i just mentioned that it uses a gp. If you downvoted that please remove it.

Comment: It doesn't even use a geometric progression. Your formula for the n-th term fails for the third one already.

Comment: N is the last term not number of sequence elements. Please read the post carefully

Comment: Okay, please explain to me how `a*r^(n-1)`, for `a=r=-2`, will EVER be `-6` or `-10`.

Comment: i have same question of (user568109)